# Why are speeds of different EM waves in vacuum not EXACTLY equal?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light, measurements, error-analysis

It is said in my textbook (reference below) that the different waves of the Electromagnetic Spectrum have velocities **almost equal** to each other. (Variations are within a few m/s according to my textbook). The precise wording in the book is:

> The velocity of electromagnetic waves in free space or vacuum is an
>   important fundamental constant. It has been shown by experiments on
>   electromagnetic waves of different wavelengths that this velocity is the
>   same (independent of wavelength) to within a few metres per second, out
>   of a value of $3 \times 10^8$ m/s.

Why not **exactly equal**?

Is it due to lack of such high-precision measuring devices that are yet to be discovered? If not what's the reason? Please clarify.

Also, is it possible to have another EM wave to travel **faster** than the speed of light? Logically asking, Why not?

The book is NCERT STD 12th Physics, chapter 8 section 8.3.2. p.276-277. [link to PDF of chapter 8](http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph108.pdf).

Comment: Through matter or through vacuum?  It makes all the difference.

Comment: In a vacuum all frequencies of EM waves move **exactly** at the speed of light. If the light is passing through something that isn't a vacuum then the speed may depend on the frequency. We would need to see exactly what your books says to comment further.

Comment: I don't think the text book is wrong but a poor description.  I just read the text and when it says that EM waves move as close as a few meters per second to speed of light in vacuum it is describing measurements that have been made.  This difference is an error in the measurement or the variance of measured values compared to the speed of light.

Comment: Exactly: "*It has been shown by experiments [...] that this velocity is the same (independent of wavelength) to within a few metres per second*" refers to the experimental results, which unavoidably have uncertainties associated with them. That is: we believe that the velocity is the same, because that's **been measured** to within a few m/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why not exactly equal? Is it due to lack of such high-precision measuring devices that are yet to be discovered?

No experiment can ever prove that two quantities are exactly equal. All any experiment can do is to determine that the difference between the two quantities is smaller than the experimental precision. More precise devices like you mention can make that range smaller, but can never claim that they are exactly equal.

The wording in the textbook is a good example of how to correctly describe the result of an experiment that would be loosely interpreted as showing they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that the difference between the speed of light and of electromagnetic waves is due to measurement error. You are incorrect in assuming that this error still applies.

Your textbook says:

> The speed of the waves, according to these equations, turned out to be
>   very close to the speed of light( 3 ×10^8 m/s), obtained from optical measurements.

What they are saying here is that, **in Maxwell's time**, measurements of the speed of light had given a value of approximately 300,000 km/s. Maxwell's equations (using the then accepted values of the permittivity and permeability of vacuum) gave his electromagnetic waves a speed of 299,800 km/s. As a result Maxwell suggested that light is an electromagnetic wave, and that the minor difference was just measurement error.

As we now know that light is indeed an electromagnetic wave (as are radio, X-rays, etc), we know that they all propagate at the same speed c, which is now known to be **exactly 299,792.458 km/s**. The reason why this value is exact is that the metre is defined as the distance travelled by light (or other EM waves) in vacuum in $\frac1{299,792.458}$ second.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible that there happens an uncertainty to the measured wavelength especially for low-frequency EM waves such as radio waves. That is, when a single radio wave is emitted from, e.g., an antenna, a receiver (a wave-peak detector, for instance) located far apart from the emitter may be activated as receiving a point close to the *peak* but not necessarily the *peak* itself. And it seems that the lower the frequency, the more precise the detector must be used, otherwise the receiver works sooner or later than the expected time which culminates in errors in measuring the exact values for the speed of light.

Besides, the mentioned text maybe is simply pointing out that the speed of light is not exactly equal to $3×10^8 \space m/s$ but rather is $299792458 \space m/s$, which, as stated in the text, is

> a few metres per second, out of a value of $3×10^8 \space m/s$